# Integrating automatic adding of reference into sub (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, reference, ms-word

How do I integrate my code that activates a reference (if it's not already activated) into the beginning of a code I've already got? The problem seems to be the newly added reference isn't recognized as active if I try activating and calling them within the same sub... any suggestions? When I run them separately they run just fine. I'm getting a 4120 Run-time Error (bad parameter) which also happens when reference isn't activated

```
Sub test ()
Dim strGUID As String, theRef As Variant, i As Long

 'Update the GUID you need below.
strGUID = "{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"


 'Remove any missing references
For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
    If theRef.isbroken = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
    End If
'Check if the reference isn't already activatet - can cause issues when stepping through but works just fine
    If ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i).GUID = strGUID Then
    GoTo ContinueSub
    End If
Next i

 'Add the reference
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0
Run "ContractPrep"

ContinueSub:
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object

'Bunch of code here and then the error occurs here:
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Temp)
'show the word document - put outside of loop for speed later
wdApp.Visible = True

    wdDoc.Application.Selection.Wholestory
    openxml = wdDoc.Application.Selection.WordOpenXML   
    wdDoc.Application.Selection.Delete

'Rest of code
End Sub
```

Comment: The project needs to be recompiled after adding a reference.  I'd split it into 2 subs - have the first add the reference, and then schedule the rest of the code to run with `Application.OnTime`. It should recompile itself in between the 2 calls.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the input!